# How to set multiple image views in rounded shape

Tags: android, imageview

I want to set ***multiple imageviews*** in ***rounded view*** and when I click a particular imageview I want to open a new activity.

[image]

Smething like above image.

How to place imageviews like this?

Comment: His name it's `radial menu` you can search on google to libraries.

Comment: I don't want to click on the centre. A new activity will get opened when I click an imageview which is placed in rounded way. How to use radial menu for this?

Comment: Have you searched `radial menu android` on Google? No because... there a hundred pages showing you how to do what you want.... Check this https://github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Widget-Android